# How to implement unsend messages in Instagram Graph API

Tags: rest, instagram, integration, instagram-graph-api

I have integrated Instagram graph API with Salesforce and it's working fine. Now I want to implement unsend messages but Instagram webhook is not sending any notification

I tried after subscribing "messages" webhook event but it is not sending any notification

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.